# variable size circles in Scatter plot using CorePlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am using `CorePlot` to plot a scatter plot on `iPhone`. With the help of the following code, I am able to only plot all circles with a specific radius.

```
CPTPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];

greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];

greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
```

I aim to plot circles with different radius.

Each circle of the scatter plot should have a different radius depending on the number of occurrences of the value.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method. For each data index, create a new symbol with the correct size and return it.

Look at the plot symbol test in the Mac *CPTTestApp* example app for working sample code.